# Combining RoboBrowser with Requests-HTML

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, robobrowser, python-requests-html

I like the ease of filling out and submitting online forms using RoboBrowser and I think I understand how to access the requests.Session() instance underlying RoboBrowser if I need to use that.

But I want to submit a form using RoboBrowser then pass the session to requests_html.Session() so I can render the HTML using JavaScript. How do I do that? Is there a way to convert a Requests session to a Requests-HTML session?

I have looked through the documentation for Requests, Requests-HTML and RoboBrowser, as well as through all SO questions about Requests-HTML. I have also Googled for the answer. None of these sources helped.

I am aware that it might be easier to use Selenium for this purpose, but this is for a project at work, where I cannot install Selenium. I believe my broader question of how to convert or pass a Requests session to a Requests-HTML session is a useful one for the Python community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the [Requests-HTML source code](https://html.python-requests.org/_modules/requests_html.html). There is a specific class method called `HTMLResponse._from_response()` for this purpose, which takes a response as its first argument and a session as its second argument.

Say we have a `robobrowser.RoboBrowser()` object named `browser`. Then the underlying `requests.Response()` object is accessible by `browser.response`. To pass this to a `requests_html.HTMLSession()` called `session`, do as follows:

```
import requests_html

html_response = requests_html.HTMLResponse._from_response(browser.response, session)

html_response.html.render()  # This now works
```