# Combining Requests-HTML with RoboBrowser or Mechanize

Tags: python-3.x, mechanize, robobrowser, python-requests-html

I like to fill out a form in a website either using Robobrowser or mechanize libraries in python.
But, the website I'm attempting needs javascript rendering.

I am able to render webpage javascript using requests-html. Now how do I pass my session from requests-html to robobrowser or mechanize ?

I am able to solve it using Selenium but I would prefer either Robobrowser or mechanize for that.

To be exact, I want the opposite of session transfer as mentioned in this link here:

"[Combining RoboBrowser with Requests-HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215036/combining-robobrowser-with-requests-html)"